# How to prevent an entire page refresh in Meteor when data changes?

Tags: javascript, meteor, iron-router

I use iron-router and subscribe on root level:

```
Router.configure({
    layoutTemplate: 'layout',
    loadingTemplate: 'loading',
    waitOn: function () {
        if (Meteor.user()) return [Meteor.subscribe('notifications', Meteor.user().notifications)];
    }
});
```

If users get a notification, the entire page refreshes. I only want that reactive data changes, but not the entire page. How can I fix this?

Comment: Why cant you do it with template helpers and autorun ?